# How to create a new peer for a new channel in Hyperledger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been following Hyperledger's basic network tutorial and I am exploring the possibility of having 2 peers and 2 channels, one peer for each channel.

I have already created a channel config file for the second channel called `mychannel2.tx` using configtxgen's command:

```
../bin/configtxgen -profile OneOrgChannel -outputCreateChannelTx /config/channel2.tx -channelID mychannel2
```

However, I am not sure how to create a second peer to add to this channel. My guess is I have to configure the `crypto-config.yaml` file but **I am not sure how to do that to add a peer**.

But once I add a peer, I should be able to use [basic network tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html)'s start.sh script to create a channel and have the second peer join the channel just like this:

```
# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx

# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a new peer you simply need to generate proper crypto material for that peer signed by its organization. For that purpose you can use `cryptogen` cli tool, where you simply can reuse existing `crypto-config.yaml` file, where you need to define organization with template for number of peers and how many user certificates to generate:

```
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

In example above it define two orgs with two peers and one user per each org.

Next you have to define a channel with `configtxgen` which specifies your requirements, for you case you would like to have:

> 2 peers and 2 channels, one peer for each channel.

hence need to define profile which will specify those channels, now the question whenever those peers belongs to same organization or not. Assuming they from different organizations, therefore configuration will look like following:

```
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    ChannelOne:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
    ChannelTwo:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org2
```

Now, you need to generate config transaction for both channels to generate genesis block and being able to join the channels.

```
FABRIC_CFG_PATH=. configtxgen -profile ChannelOne -channelID channelone -outputCreateChannelTx=channelone.tx

FABRIC_CFG_PATH=. configtxgen -profile ChannelTwo -channelID channeltwo -outputCreateChannelTx=channeltwo.tx
```

Finally once you have config transactions for each channel you can submit them to the ordering service creating a new channel and later to join peers into appropriate channels. Please note that you do not really need to change `crypto-config.yaml`.

Comment: Second question is if I do play with `configtx.yaml`, I must also edit the section for "Organizations" in addition to what you showed here right? (to add org 2 information in there)

Comment: First question: why don't I need to change `crypto-config.yaml`? I thought I need to use that to generate the peer artifact?

Comment: `cryptogen` tool e.g. `crypto-config.yaml` used to generate crypto material for peers, admins and users. In your case you can simply use it as is, since you need only two peers one for each org.

Comment: Currently organization section already includes Org1 and Org2, so no there is no need to change, unless there are additional details you haven't mentioned in your question.

Comment: I have made updates to `docker-compose.yml` to add a new org `peer0.org2.example.com` (and gave it new ports), I have also added Org2 in `configtx.yaml` and made the Host: `peer0.org2.example.com`, and I have updated `crypto-config.yaml` and added an org under PeerOrgs. I ran the cryptogen command and successfully generated 2 peers, ran the configtxgen command and made 2 channels, however, when I run my start scripts to start up the container I keep getting `Error: No such container: peer0.org2.example.com`. Can I possibly message you on Slack to figure this out?

Comment: find me on chat.hyperledger.org @C0rWin

Comment: strange, didn't get any messages yet :/

Comment: sorry I sent it initially on Slack, just re-read your comment and re-sent it to `chat.hyperledger.org`, please let me know if you can see the attached files. Thanks!